# Apache Airflow Celery Redis DecodeError

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Using the latest version of apache airflow. Started out with LocalExecutor, under that mode everything was working fine, except some interactions the web UI state that the CeleryExecutor was needed to use them. Installed and configured the Celery executor with Redis, configured Redis as the broker URL and the result backend.

It appears to work at first, until a task is scheduled at which point it gives the following error:

```
 File "/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 882, in scheduler
    job.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 201, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1311, in _execute
    self._execute_helper(processor_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1444, in _execute_helper
    self.executor.heartbeat()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/base_executor.py", line 132, in heartbeat
    self.sync()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 91, in sync
    state = async.state
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 436, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 375, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 352, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 668, in _get_task_meta_for
    return self.decode_result(meta)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 271, in decode_result
    return self.meta_from_decoded(self.decode(payload))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 278, in decode
    accept=self.accept)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 263, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 263, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
kombu.exceptions.DecodeError: invalid load key, '{'.
```

Seems to be a pickle serialization error, but I'm not sure how to trace the cause. Any suggestions?

This issue consistently affects a workflow where I use the subdag feature, perhaps the problem is related to that.

NOTE: I also tested using rabbitMQ, had a different problem there; client shows "connection reset by peer" and crashes. RabbitMQ log shows "client unexpectedly closed TCP connection".

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this after seeing the exact same backtrace in our scheduler logs:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
kombu.exceptions.DecodeError: invalid load key, '{'.
```

The fact that celery was trying to unpickle something that starts with '{' seemed suspicious, so I took a tcpdump of the traffic and triggered a task via the web UI. The resulting capture included this exchange at almost exactly the same instant that the above backtrace appeared in the scheduler logs:

```
05:03:49.145849 IP <scheduler-ip-addr>.ec2.internal.45597 > <redis-ip-addr>.ec2.internal.6379: Flags [P.], seq 658:731, ack 46, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 654768546 ecr 4219564282], length 73: RESP "GET" "celery-task-meta-b0d3a29e-ac08-4e77-871e-b4d553502cc2"
05:03:49.146086 IP <redis-ip-addr>.ec2.internal.6379 > <scheduler-ip-addr>.ec2.internal.45597: Flags [P.], seq 46:177, ack 731, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 4219564282 ecr 654768546], length 131: RESP "{"status": "SUCCESS", "traceback": null, "result": null, "task_id": "b0d3a29e-ac08-4e77-871e-b4d553502cc2", "children": []}"
```

The payload of the response from Redis is clearly JSON, so why is celery trying to unpickle it? We're in the process of migrating from Airflow 1.7 to 1.8, and during our rollout we have one fleet of Airflow workers running v1.7 and another running v1.8. The workers were supposed to pull from queues with disjoint workloads, but due to a bug in one of our DAGs, we had a TaskInstance scheduled by Airflow 1.8 that was then executed by a celery worker launched via Airflow 1.7.

[AIRFLOW-1038](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/c39d91537bb8c28cc81aad3e26eff72158e3b1f4) changed the serializer for celery task statuses from JSON (the default) to pickle, so workers running a version of the code before this change will serialize the results in JSON, and schedulers running a version of the code that include this change will try to deserialize the results by unpickling, which causes the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify what kind of celery_result_backend you have configured in airflow.cfg. Try switching it to a database backend (mysql etc) if that isn't the case.

We see that with a ampq backend (only available on Celery 3.1 and below) ,redis and rpc backend there are sometimes issues.

Answer (score 0):

We faced this, our configuration management hadn't been properly updated so the scheduler and some workers were on apache-airflow 1.8.2 while a significant pool of workers were running airflow 1.8.0. Check that all your nodes are running the same version of airflow.